# Find out which blob has the pixel location [x,y]?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a labelled blob image using bwlabel, I want to find a blob which has the pixel location [x,y] and display it by removing the rest of blobs.
Here is the code I wrote, but it doesn't give correct answer, please fix this

```
[y, x] = ginput(1);
x = round(x);
y = round(y); % here x and y is a location of blob i want to keep

    BW = bwlabel(newImgg,4) ; % labelled image contains several blobs
%     figure, imshow(BW, [])
    props = regionprops(logical(BW),'all');
    while(1)
        for k = 2:length(props)
            if ismember([x,y],props(k,1).PixelList) == [1, 1];
                keeperIndex = k;
                break
            end
        end
        break
    end

    keeperBlobsImage = ismember(BW, keeperIndex);
    keeperBlobsImage = imfill(keeperBlobsImage,'holes');
    figure, imshow(keeperBlobsImage,[])
```

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment because I don't know Matlab. Maybe you can colour each of the detected blobs with a unique colour in a copy of your image, then see what colour that pixel is to determine which blob it belongs to.

Comment: I am working with medical dicom images which are basically gray scale and i don't want to change the pixel values and i don't think that is what I was trying to do, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I do not currently have a MATLAB license, so I wouldn't be able to test this on my machine, I've also been away from MATLAB syntax for a while. Here's an idea:

[From MATLAB's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), `PixelList` is an array where each row is formatted `[x,y,...]`, depending on your dimensions.

Working with your image I'm assuming `PixelList` has the format `[x,y]`

Looping through `PixelList`, keep track of the indices you want to discard. If you measured `n` pixels:

```
discardList = []
for i = 1:n
    if (PixelList(i) != [target_x,target_y]
        discardList=[discardList,i]
    end
end
newPixelList = PixelList
newPixelList(discardList) = []
```

Again, I haven't used MATLAB for a decent amount of time now, so I apologize for any problems in the syntax (brackets, loops, and conditionals)

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

According to the MATLAB's documentation, it shows `bwlabel` being used only on a BW image. So make sure you're doing that, I guess.

Also, on the output of `regionprops` you should have `WeightedCentroid`.

From your `ginput`, find the region where the centroid  is the closest.

My suggestion would be to use the [vision.BlobAnalysis System Object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.blobanalysis-class.html)

```
[y,x] = ginput(1)
bA = vision.BlobAnalysis;
centroids = step(bA,BWImage);
```

using the documentation make sure you turn off all "output ports" of the system object, and keep the centroid output port on.

```
d = 1e10;
d2 = 0;
dArr = [x,y;0,0]
cIndex=0;
for i = 1:length(centroids)
    dArr(2,:) = centroids(i,:);
    d2 = pdist(dArr);
    if (d2<d)
        d = d2;
        cIndex = i;
    end
end
```

The variable `cIndex` will contain the index of the blob you need. You can run blob analysis and isolate it from the rest

Comment: I am not looking for pixelList, i want to determine which blob has the [x,y] cordinates described initially and i want to retrieve that single blob. Check my code above i used PixelList but i think i made mistake somewhere

Comment: @Gopi the solution I posted checks every pixel's location. If you look at the if condition in the loop. At the end, it removes all pixels that don't have that location you're looking for

Comment: Yes, understood your code, so the output of your code is the single pixel value that that matches [target x, target y]. which i already have, is their anyway i can find which blob does this match belong to, It would be great if you can write a whole code which checks all blobs and gives output index of single blob which contains [targetx, target y]. Thanks, Gopi

Comment: Let me look at the MATLAB documentation. I don't have a way to run MATLAB so whatever I write _will not be verified_